# Android contacts accounts

Tags: android, contacts

I need to add new contacts dynamically from my application.
I list all the phone accounts with the AccountManager getAccounts method but I get accounts like weather, stock, etc.
How can I get only contact accounts ?

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no good way to do this by using the API, the method we found to be most accurate was to think backwards: which accounts are used for storing contacts?

It's a bit crude, but it gives pretty good results (cache the list and you don't need to do it every time).

```
// Pseudo-code
for contact in RawContacts
    uniqueAccountTypes.put(contact.account)
for accountType in uniqueAccountTypes
    uniqueAccountsWithContacts.putAll(accountManager.getAccountsByType(accountType))
```

I don't have access a copy of the contacts database right now, so the code above might be slightly off, but the concept should be clear. Let me know if I should clarify further.

Comment: This method wont work in all cases. The default contacts app can do it, so there must be some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation.

After a little search found this method of AccountManager:

```
getAccountsByTypeAndFeatures();
```

here if you set parameter features as "service_mail" , "service_talk" etc, you will get accounts supporting e-mail and chat, hence these accounts will support contacts also.

**UPDATE**

"service_ah" will give the account device is linked to.